# Rails ajax error call text not showing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have:

```
  def rate
    @konkurrencer = Rating.where(:IP => @ip, :konkurrencer_id => params[:id])
    if @konkurrencer.empty?
    render :nothing => true
    else
    render :status => 500, :text => "This server hosted at sadasa"
    end
   end
end
```

My ajax call:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
             url: frm.attr('action'), //your server side script
             data: frm.serialize(), //our data
             type: 'POST',
             success: function (data) {
            $('.warning').fadeIn(500).css({display: 'block',
                position: 'absolute',
                left: position.left + 50,
                top: position.top - 25
            }).html('Du har stemt').fadeOut(1000),
            $(ri).next('.ratingcount').html('asdasdasd')
            },
             error: function (msg) {
                 alert(msg); //something went wrong.
             }
         });
```

The problem is that the message that is showed in the alert is `[object Object]` and not the text `This server hosted at sadasa`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might happen mainly because the error function of jQuery ajax's could have 3 arguments: `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`. The first is XMLHttpRequest object. See more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**Solution**
Try to replace your error function to:

```
error: function (responseObject) {
    alert(responseObject.responseText); //something went wrong.
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Change `alert(msg)` to `alert(msg.responseText)`